# GWT: process messages?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to display a gif that indicates loading (a spinning wheel). My method is:

```
public void load() {
    loadIndicator.setVisible(true);
    ... the loading code ...
    loadIndicator.setVisible(false);
}
```

but this is not working. I suppose it is because the elements are only redrawn at the end of the process. Is there anything like `redraw` or like in other languages (C#) `Application.Doevents` or something like that? Or am I using the wrong method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most code that loads something from a server does so asynchronously. This means that all of your load() method may run before 'the loading code' finishes - the load indicator is made visible, the load is started (but not finished), and the indicator is gone again. This is done (in part) to not need to worry about waiting for the server before allowing more user interaction.

No redraw method should be necessary for almost any GWT code out there. Events are a good idea for getting your app to be designed around async processes.

Useful thread to understand writing async code: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/faca1575f306ba0f/3be719c021aa19bd